# Probability of Two Samples Containing Overlapping Data

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, sampling, hypergeometric-distribution

Quick question about sampling a data population that contains non-overlapping data: if I take two samples of 50 from a population of 100,000 unique data points, how would I calculate the probability of the two samples containing a shared data point?

As well, how do I determine the population size required for the probability of overlap to be below a certain point (0.05%) for $n=50$?
Thanks.

Comment: Since this seems to be routine bookwork similar to what might be assigned in a subject or done as an exercise, it should carry the `self-study` tag. Please read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question accordingly. If you don't think it counts as self-study, please explain the context in which such a question arises.

Answer (score 3):

Since this looks like bookwork - and you clearly even know *which distribution you're supposed to use* - I'll avoid doing it directly in those terms, and just outline the basic logic.

Imagine you have a big urn with 100,000 grey balls in it (maybe one in the shape of a small skip). Take your first sample, painting those 50 balls red and return them.

Now you draw the second sample. Easy question: What is the chance you draw no red balls?

(1) quick approximation: removing a few grey balls won't change the probability much, so we can approximate it by doing it as if it were sampling with replacement.

P(0 red balls) = $(0.9995)^{50}$ = 0.975304

So the chance of one or more red balls in the second sample is about 2.5%

This is handy because it gives us a reasonableness check; the real answer should be close but a little smaller.

(2) Exact - sampling without replacement.

P(0 red balls) = $(1-\frac{50}{100000})\times(1-\frac{50}{99999})\times(1-\frac{50}{99998})\times \ldots\times(1-\frac{50}{99951})$

The answer is very similar to the earlier approximation (as expected, is close but a little smaller). Given the hints here already, you should be able to cast it directly into [hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) terms ... though starting by doing it from first principles may be a better way to start.

> how do I determine the population size required for the probability of overlap to be below a certain point (0.05%) for n=50?

A calculation almost identical to the one above. You could get a very close idea from the approximate calculation I did. To do it more exactly, write the inequality for the probability in terms of factorials (hypergeometric), use Stirlings approximation, cancel out everything you reasonably can, solve to get a lower bound for n.

Answer (score 0):

ref to Markatou, M., et al. (2005). "Analysis of Variance of Cross-Validation Estimators of the Generalization Error." J. Mach. Learn. Res. 6: 1127-1168.

it is a hypergeometric distribution.